# Can I get a patch out of git with only the conflicts?

Tags: git, patch

I am using `git` and am rebasing a branch on top of another branch. During the rebase there are conflicts. Can I get a `patch` file with only the conflicts?

Originally, I thought that during the rebase, when I have all the conflicts unmerged/unstaged, I can do the following:

```
$ git diff > /tmp/conflicts.patch
```

However, when I try to apply the resulting patch, it fails:

```
$ git rebase --abort
$ git apply /tmp/conflicts.patch
 error: unrecognized input
$ patch -p1 < /tmp/conflicts.patch
 patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

I also tried to diff with the `--no-prefix` option, but the result was the same.

To be honest, I have never worked with patch files, but neither `patch` nor `git` are very helpful with their error messages, so googling didn't provide much info.

Any ideas? This is an excerpt of the resulting patch:

```
diff --cc app/common/models/api/requests/index.js
index c9bf20d,7578fbb..0000000
--- a/app/common/models/api/requests/index.js
+++ b/app/common/models/api/requests/index.js
@@@ -12,7 -12,9 +12,11 @@@ require('./NewUserDS')
  require('./NewSubscriptionDS');
  require('./PasswordResetRequestDS');
  require('./RefreshTokensRequestDS');
 -require('./TwoFactorConfirmationRequestDS');
  require('./UpdateUserRequestDS');
 -require('./UserAddressRequestDS');
 -require('./PicOptimizationDS');
  require('./ProxyRequestDS');
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +require('./GDPRPreferencesDS');
 +
++=======
+ require('./ListTournamentsQuery');
++>>>>>>> (#36) Implement Multiple Streams for single match
```

Comment: The short answer is "no": these diffs are *combined diffs*, which show two different sets of changes combined, and omit some changes, and no patch-like program (neither `patch` nor `git apply`) can deal with that. Applying a patch means "one input, one output" not "two partial inputs, one partial outputs".

Comment: @torek thanks for the comment - that's at least pointing me in a direction. I don't necessarily want to use only the tools or the approach that I have described above. If you could suggest an alternative, that would be even more helpful.

Comment: Hmm, having thought more about this, it really seems that I want to achieve something impossible - I want to resolve future merge/rebase conflicts without actually merging/rebasing, which seems to be impossible, since the changes that would "resolve" the future conflicts would themselves conflict when actually merging/rebasing...

Comment: That sounds right, but you might also want to look at `git rerere` (which re-uses re-corded re-solutions, hence the silly name). Essentially, you just enable it then do the merge, and Git records what you did and does the same thing again next time.